# Tethering Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110) via Nokia E71

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tethering, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

I have a data plan on my Nokia E71 phone, and I would like to share it for my brand new Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110) which has no 3G. Bluetooth would be fine as would creating a WiFi hotspot, however so far I haven't gotten any method to do the trick. Even wired by USB would be fine, if it just worked.

- On the Nokia E71 I have [JoikuSpot](http://www.joiku.com/products/joikuspot_light) installed, but stock Android ICS does not work with the ad hoc network that it creates. I rooted the tab and tried installing different versions of `wpa_supplicant` that I could find, but none of them really worked on this tab.
- I have paired the devices using Bluetooth, which appears to work fine – however, I don't know how exactly I could get connected to the internet. I believe there is something obvious that I've missed here. If I need some app (in either end), please tell me which app. (I guess it basically does not work because Nokia does no PAN while Android is ignorant of DUN, but I might be very wrong.)
- I don't have any cables that I could use to connect the devices by USB or similar, but if a working solution exists, I would be happy to buy some. (I've already used many many hours for this.)

**EDIT**: I no longer have the Nokia phone, nor the Samsung Tab, so I cannot really test the suggestions posted here. As far as I am concerned, this question can be closed. (While I do understand that any answers might be helpful for other people, I still cannot test whether they work or not. Therefore, it also does not make a lot of sense to accept any answer, does it?)

Comment: Have you tried [WiFi Tether for Root Users](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.android.wifi.tether)?

Comment: @onik: No, I have not. I don't think it solves the problem, because my Android device has no 3G connection to share. I think if my phone had Android, then this would be one possible solution, but as of now it is not, I believe.

Comment: I just thought that since it enables creating Ad Hoc networks, maybe it would enable connecting to JoikuSpot's Ad Hoc network.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried, but it did not help: the ad hoc network remains invisible. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

On the android 4 system install BlueVPN.

If your phone has bluetooth and can act as a modem you need to pair the phone and your android device. When pairing enable the option in the phone to let the other device to connect.

Be sure that on your sim card you have a contract that support WAP connections enabled (otherwise it can be very expensive).

Get the provider access point info (some times called APN) and set it into the BlueVPN settings.

If your phone already goes into internet with gprs or 3G, you can get the string directly from the settings of your phone.

On my Nokia (Xpress musik 5800) I went to Settings-Connectivity-Access Points-WAP services and there I found all the needed informations in order to configure BlueVPN.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my galaxy tab 2 7" and a nokia n900
Solved it by enabling bluetooth dun on n900 and installing 2 apps on the tab : BlueDUN trial ,and BlueVPN ics by Mirko Solazzi ,available on google play.
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried to get it to work for about two hours or so, but with no success. :(

Comment: I also have a n900 and a galaxy tab 2 (10") I have tried to connect my Tab to my N900 with BlueVPN. Till now it's not working. What are your settings?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with [BlueVPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluevpn) installed on my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and using my Nokia E71 data plan. It is not necessary to install any app on your Nokia phone.

Open BlueVPN on your tab and set the configuration info of your data plan (access point, number, username, password, etc.). Then, pair the devices from the phone and authorize the tablet to always connect to the phone.

In BlueVPN, click the phone device in the list of available devices and wait until it connects. Now you can access internet from you tablet. If the connection fails, try changing the BlueVPN settings for compatibility.